# Storing and reading user and product images in SQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

In our application we have users and products. An user can have one profile picture and product can have 0 or max 10 pictures

At the moment table are:

```
- users{id, name, birthday}
- products{id, title, description, price}
```

How to store picture? To be able to increase product max number of pictures, and efficient to retrieve a product with all picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways you could do this depending on the scale fo your app and depending on how far you wanted to take it. There are all sorts of arguments about storing images as BLOBS, but it's a much better option (IMO) to store REFERENCES to images (E.g. 'https://example.com/myimage.jpg'), as you can then utilise things like CDNs and proxy caching. As for the DB design, the two simplest options are:

***one-to-many***
You store a table for each 'type' of image, relating the images to IDs of the entity you are relating it to. E.g

```
- user_images{id,user_id,url}
- product_images{id,product_id,url}
```

An example usage would be:

```
INSERT INTO user_images (user_id, url) VALUES (1, 'http://url/to/my/image.jpg')
INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, url) VALUES (1, 'http://url/to/my/image.jpg')
INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, url) VALUES (1, 'http://url/to/my/image2.jpg')
```

This would allow you to have multiple product images all assigned to the same product. It would also allow you to store multiple images for each user, which might be useful for history (if you want to store every user's previous image).

If you don't need multiple images per user, simply store a text field in your users table with the url of the image.

**Polymorphic one-to-many**
Going down this route would allow you to store your image references in one table, and with each reference you simply store the 'type' of image it is - E.g.

```
-images{id,type,object_id,url}
```

a usage of this might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO images (type, object_id, url) VALUES ('user', 1, 'http://url/to/my/image.jpg')
INSERT INTO images (type, object_id, url) VALUES ('product', 1, 'http://url/to/my/image.jpg')
```

So, ths first example would be storing an image for a user with an ID of 1, and the second is storing an image reference for a product, with an ID of 1. This is a Polymorphic one-to-many as each entity can have multiple image references. The advantage of this is it makes image processing much easier, as all your image references are in one place.

Comment: Storing is simple but how to retrieve the images "SELECT products.* , images.url FROM products,images WHERE products.id={productId} AND images.id=products.id" this query wont work I guess. So what is the working solution

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work for you. In case you need modification do let me know in comment.

products table

```
id | name
------------
10 | Lenovo
11 | grocered
12 | Light
```

images table

```
id | product_id | link
------------------------
101 | 10 | link 1
102 | 10 | link 2
103 | 11 | link 3
104 | 12 | link 4
104 | 12 | link 5
```

SQL query to fetch the images as coma separated

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.link ORDER BY i.link ) AS images
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 6;
```